# Python-telegram-bot. Открыть меню "Прикрепить" после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

У бота есть всего одна кнопка — "Загрузить файл". По сценарию пользователь нажимает на нее, а затем загружает файл. Есть ли в библиотеке функционал, который позволит открыть меню с прикреплением документов, после нажатия на эту кнопку?

Comment: Я думаю по сценарию ты можешь ожидать от него файл нужного тебе формата просто напросто, а не открывать меню прикрепления файла телеграма. А всё что не этого формата отклонять и предупредждать об этом пользователя

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что могу использовать что-то вроде `(MessageHandler(Filters.text, my_foo))` , но задача, которую мне поставили звучит так.

Comment: В ботапи - точно ничего подобного нет, на 99% уверен что и в mtproto без стороннего клиента сие не реализуемо.... (вы по сути хотите приложением клиента телеги управлять причем не со своей стороны)

Comment: Да, возможно некорректная формулировка в задаче. Спасибо